POST (url) 500 (Internal Server Error) en una solicitud fetch
Estoy realizando una pagina web con MVC ASP.NET, donde el usuario ingresa datos en un formulario y la pagina reemplaza los datos del usuario en una plantilla de word, y despues la descarga en PDF.
Al momento de realizar una solicitud con fetch para el envio de datos, en el servidor que lo tengo me aparece este error POST http://10.21.249.74:8080/Word/GenerateWord 500 (Internal Server Error) en la consola del navegador, y me marca que es del lado de mi fetch. Estoy usando Microsoft IIS
Este es mi fetch y me marca error en la primera linea, donde va la URL:
fetch($(this).attr("action"), {
                method: "POST",
                body: formData,
            })

He intentado poner la url directamente pero ni asi funciona (en local si funciona correctamente de las dos maneras):
fetch("/Word/GenerateWord", {
                method: "POST",
                body: formData,
            })

Tengo en mi controlador llamado WordController.cs un ActionResult que se llama GenerateWord donde hago todo el proceso de reemplazar las palabras clave de mi plantilla de word con los datos que ingreso en el formulario el usuario.
Mi pregunta es si el error es por alguna configuracion del servidor o es del lado de mi codigo?
Este es mi fetch completo:
fetch($(this).attr("action"), {
                method: "POST",
                body: formData,
            })
                .then(response => {
                    // Verificar si la respuesta es exitosa
                    if (!response.ok) {
                        // Si la respuesta no es ok, lanzar un error con el mensaje correspondiente
                        throw new Error('Error ' + response.status + ': ' + response.statusText);
                    }
                    return response.blob();
                })
                .then(blob => {
                    // Ocultar logo de carga
                    hideModal();

                    // Obtener valores de ID y ComputerName del formulario
                    var windowsID = formData.get("ID");
                    var ComputerName = formData.get("ComputerName");

                    // Crear un enlace para descargar el PDF
                    var link = document.createElement('a');
                    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

                    // Personalizar el nombre del archivo
                    var fileName = windowsID + "_" + ComputerName + ".pdf";

                    //Descarga el pdf con el nombre personalizado
                    link.download = fileName;
                    link.click();

                    //Resetea el formulario despues del envio
                    document.getElementById("AssignationLetter").reset();
                    showSuccessModal();

                    // Resetear mensaje de exito después de unos segundos
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        hideModal();
                    }, 2000);

                })
                .catch(error => {
                    // En caso de error, ocultar logo de carga
                    hideLoading();
                    // Mostrar el mensaje de error específico
                    console.error('There has been a problem with your fetch operation:', error.message);
                })
                .finally(() => {
                    // Habilitar controles después de obtener la respuesta o en caso de error
                    enableFormControls();
                });

Gracias.

El error 500 es un error de servidor y tu solo has colocado código del cliente
